# npm build failure in Azure deveops pipline

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines

I am facing this issue while building dist file in azure devops pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acidn.png)

peice of code in package.json file is:

```
"name": "aimportal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer --output-hashing none --watch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

angular version : 9.0.1

I tride by deleting package.json file and added the same node js version but still facing the issue.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please try the same `npm build` for your project from your local machine to see whether the same issue exists. If same issue occurs, the problem should be laying on your project itself rather than Azure Pipelines. You may need to check the configurations of your project.

Comment: I found the issue, actually issue is coz while doing build with the above command in local machine also , the build is not closed after successfully completion of build that's why we facing the issue in pipeline. I am facing another issue as while doing build with 'ng build --prod' files in dist folder are created with the es5 and es-2015 extension, after doing deployement with this dist folder my app unable to get script file

Comment: can you please show me a solution to resolve this issue @BrightRan-MSFT

Comment: Hi @venu, Based on your last comment, the same issue exists wehn building on the local machine. And the problem is because of the build process was not closed by the `ng build` command after completed. So, the issue should be related to the `ng build` command or your project itself rather than Azure DevOps. For your another issue, it also should be related to the `ng build` command or your project itself.
As I have suggested above, you need to check the configurations in your project to see if there are any wrong settings or you have missed some things.